# PHONETIC function doesn't work in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, japanese

I stumbled across the PHONETIC function, which apparently is supposed to generate furigana readings for Japanese kanji. So if I put in 東京都 to Cell A1, and in cell A2 I write:

```
=PHONETIC(A1)
```

It should generate トウキョウト, which is the phonetic representation of the Japanese characters. But it only generates N/A. I've seen other people post this problem on forums, but to no response.

If this doesn't work, is there any other way I can automatically generate furigana readings from kanji using Excel formulae?

Answer (score -1):

Hello I just found the reason why. here's the link (Japanese Only):

http://www.relief.jp/itnote/archives/002644.php

First Step. Verify your Language Settings.

1.- Options
2.- Language
3.- Make sure that Japanese is at the top on both, interface and proofing language.
4.- If the language does not appear you might need to download a language pack.

Second Step. Make sure that the Kanji input contains phonetic information.

This means that the input text in each cell must have done using furigana and then converted to kanji. (trough Microsoft IME for example).

If this is not the case you are out of luck my friend, if the input is a copied kanji from a different workbook this will not work. even if is copied from one worksheet to another.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not work, or at least you have not explained it correctly. The sample worksheet at the Japanese link does not display furigana as claimed.

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to get it to work if you change the language to Japanese (in Preferences) and restart excel.